# Cypher match nodes with less that X relations of a given type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given this data I would like to cypher query the neo4j database for all users that have less that X friends where X is their own `friend_limit` property. I've tried several `COUNT` queries but failed to get consistent results.

For example in this case I'd like to receive a resultset with all users except Joe (who 2 out of 2 friends) and Ella (how has 1 out of 1).

```
CREATE 
(Joe:User { name:'Joe', friend_limit:2 }),
(James:User {name: 'James', friend_limit:2}),
(Jack:User {name: 'Jack', friend_limit:2}),
(Jane:User {name: 'Jane', friend_limit:2}),
(Ella:User {name: 'Ella', friend_limit:1}),
(Ann:User {name: 'Ann', friend_limit:2}),

(Joe)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(Ella),
(Joe)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(James),
(James)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(Jack),
(Ella)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(Jane)
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/gbnw5s

---

Edit: i've come as far as this but I can't find a way to also include Ann in the resultset, she probably is missing because she doesn't have any `FRIENDS_WITH` relation thus fails the `MATCH` part?

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]-(u:User) 
WITH n, count(r) AS nr_of_friends 
WHERE nr_of_friends < n.friend_limit 
RETURN n, n.friend_limit, nr_of_friends
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/vjy1lt

Comment: You can probably split the query up, to use the normal match for people with `FRIENDS_WITH` relationships and another one for those without them.

Answer (score 3):

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WITH u 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(f:User) 
WITH u, count(f) AS friendCount 
WHERE friendCount < u.friend_limit 
RETURN u, friendCount
```

works (use an Optional Match to get Ann). Though I had to first do match all using

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WITH u
```

not sure if there is a better way to do that

Comment: That's the desired result thanks! Not gonna accept just yet to see if someone comes up with a solution for the MATCH all thing. Don't know if it's an issue though.

Comment: Cool, I am also waiting to see whats the better way to do this. It might be an issue on a graph with a huge number of users cos you're matching them all, but then again you want to do that :-)

Comment: I don't think you need the `WITH u`, and unless users can be friends with non-users you don't need to bind the 'other' user (`f`). I tried to profile the query with & without `WITH` to see the difference but the profiler fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: Can't profile the same pipe twice`, don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a similar way to @Luanne, just a little more concisely:

```
MATCH (u:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(f:User) 
WITH u, count(f) AS friendCount 
WHERE friendCount < u.friend_limit 
RETURN u, friendCount
```

I have left `f:User` because I think it makes it a little more efficient, especially if the model changed at a later date so that a User could be friends with something other than a user (but that would probably have a different relationship type anyway).

Comment: True, the WITH seems to be redundant. Though still not sure if there is a way to drop the entire User match. Even splitting the query as suggested by Michael I think means a full User match to find the balance users without any friends